# Retrieve data 60 days prior to their retest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to retrieve Row(s) 60 days prior to their "Retest Date" which is a column present in the table.  I have also attached the screenshot and the field "Retest Date" is highlighted.

| reagentlotid | reagentlotdesc | u_retest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| RL-0000004 | NULL | 2021-09-30 17:00:00.00 |
| RL-0000005 | NULL | 2021-09-29 04:21:00.00 |
| RL-0000006 | NULL | 2021-09-29 04:22:00.00 |
| RL-0000007 | Y-T4 | 2021-08-28 05:56:00.00 |
| RL-0000008 | NULL | 2021-09-30 05:56:00.00 |
| RL-0000009 | NULL | 2021-09-28 04:23:00.00 |

This is what I was trying to do in SQL Server:

```sql
select r.reagentlotid, r.reagentlotdesc, r.u_retestdt
from reagentlot r
where u_retestdt = DATEADD(DD,60,GETDATE());
```

But, it didn't work. The above query returning 0 rows.
Could please someone help me with this query?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `u_retestdt = DATEADD(DD,60,GETDATE())` compares the datetime down to the millisecond, so its pretty unlikely to ever have an exact match.

Comment: I have no idea what rows you are trying to retrieve.  Do you just want the last 60 days of rows, relative to the current date?  If so, that is not what the question is asking.

Comment: No,rows whose retest date are 60 days from now.. something like this-->> system date +60 days

Comment: @Dale K okay understood I need to remove the timestamp to get the exact matches

Answer (score 3):

Use a range, if you want all data from the day 60 days hence:

```
select r.reagentlotid, r.reagentlotdesc, r.u_retestdt
from reagentlot r
where 
  u_retestdt >= CAST(DATEADD(DD,60,GETDATE())
AS DATE) AND
  u_retestdt < CAST(DATEADD(DD,61,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

Dates are like numbers; the time is like a decimal part. 12:00:00 is half way through a day so it's like x.5 - SQLServer even lets you manipulate datetime types by adding fractions of days etc (adding 0.5 is adding 12h)

If you had a column of numbers like 1.1, 1.5. 2.4 and you want all the one-point-somethings you can't get any of them by saying `score = 1`; you say `score >= 1 and score < 2`

Generally, you should try to avoid manipulating table data in a query's WHERE clause because it usually makes indexes unusable: if you want "all numbers between 1 and 2", use a range; don't chop the decimal off the table data in order to compare it to 1. Same with dates; don't chop the time off - use a range:

```
--yes
WHERE score >= 1 and score < 2
--no
WHERE CAST(score as INTEGER) = 1

--yes
WHERE birthdatetime >= '1970-01-01' and birthdatetime < '1970-01-02'
--no
WHERE CAST(birthdatetime as DATE) = '1970-01-01'
```

Note that I *am* using a CAST to cut the time off in my recommendation to you, but that's to establish a pair of constants of "midnight on the day 60 days in the future" and "midnight on 61 days in the future" that will be used in the range check.

Follow the rule of thumb of "avoid calling functions on columns in a where clause" and generally, you'll be fine :)

Comment: There must be a dup out there... but I can't find one.

Comment: Right... well written... this will now be my dup answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. -60 days may be the current or previous year. HTH

```
;with doy1 as (
select DATENAME(dayofyear, dateadd(day,-60,GetDate())) as doy
)
, doy2 as (
    select case when doy > 0 then doy
                when doy < 0 then 365 - doy end as doy
    , case when doy > 0 then year(getdate())
                when doy < 0 then year(getdate())-1 end as yr
    from doy1
)
select r.reagentlotid
, r.reagentlotdesc
, cast(r.u_retestdt as date) as u_retestdt
from reagentlot r 
inner join doy2 d on DATENAME(dayofyear, r.u_retestdt) = d.doy
where DATENAME(dayofyear, r.u_retestdt) = doy
and year(r.u_retestdt) = d.yr
```